# git graph and commits on the right before merge commit

Tags: git, graph

Trying to understand the next git graph from SmartGit,[image]

As you can see the red commit is done by my partner(User2). The next green commit is done by me(User1). Then the yellow commit is done by my partner and the blue commit is the merge commit done again by my partner. So:

- Why my commit (green one) shows on the right instead on the left?
- When the graph shows commits on the right, what does it mean?
- What I think is that User2 had the yellow commit in his local, but
  when he    wanted to push it, he had to pull first the new commits
  from    the    remote(green commit), so there was a merge commit
  between the       green and yellow commit and he pushed this new
  merge commit, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretation is exactly correct. When `User2` pulled from the remote in order to be able to push, `git pull` did the merge, and that merge brought your `User1` changes into their local branch.

In general, there is not much important to right or left in the graph, but the normal graph display is that the first parent of a commit goes left, the second parent (the one that was merged into the first) goes right. So the commit of the user who ran `git pull` goes left, the other right.

If you want cleaner trees, without bubbles, you could consider using `git pull --rebase`, a solution I personally much prefer. That would have rebased `BigDecimal.ZERO` on top of `actualizaciones...` instead of creating a merge bubble. The usual word of caution about rebasing: it is only for private local branches that you've never pushed. But `git pull --rebase` respects that word of caution, so it's OK.